# Graphs not showing in Observium

Tags: observium

I have installed observium which is suceessfully pulling all information from all devices but it is not showing graphs.
[image]

I can see files in /opt/observium/rrd

I do not see any error when I manually execute:

```
cd /opt/observium && ./discovery.php -h all && ./poller.php -h all
```

I have tested in Chrome and Firefox.

This is my config.php

```
<?php

## Check http://www.observium.org/docs/config_options/ for documentation of possible settings

// Database config ---  This MUST be configured
$config['db_extension'] = 'mysqli';
$config['db_host']      = '192.168.1.10';
$config['db_user']      = 'observium';
$config['db_pass']      = 'somepass';
$config['db_name']      = 'observium';

// Base directory
#$config['install_dir'] = "/opt/observium";

// Default community list to use when adding/discovering
$config['snmp']['community'] = array("public");

// Authentication Model
$config['auth_mechanism'] = "mysql";    // default, other options: ldap, http-auth, please see documentation for config help

// Enable alerter
// $config['poller-wrapper']['alerter'] = TRUE;

//$config['web_show_disabled'] = FALSE;    // Show or not disabled devices on major pages.

// Set up a default alerter (email to a single address)
$config['email']['default']        = "admin@mydomain.com";
$config['email']['from']           = "Observium <observium@mydomain.com>";
$config['email']['default_only']   = TRUE;

$config['enable_syslog']                = 1; // Enable Syslog

// End config.php
```

If I can provide any other information which could solve this please let me know.

Seetings:
[image]

Device graph settings:
[image]

Nginx conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name observium.mydomain.com;

  root /opt/observium/html;
  client_max_body_size 10m;
  client_body_buffer_size 8K;
  client_header_buffer_size 1k;
  large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;

  location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Whats your browser console say?

Comment: DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://observium.mydomain.com/css/bootstrap-select.css.map
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://observium.mydomain.com/js/bootstrap-select.js.map

Comment: @LawrenceCherone -that is not problem. I have found that graphs <img are in code and when I open directly that graph.php img is black.

Comment: Im not familiar with observium, I was presuming they use js based graphs not images, and something was broke.

Answer (score 1):

Found problem.
At the top of config.php file was empty line before `<?php`